# How to pass check box value to php ? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have table and with check box(able to checkall), how do i pass the value from check box to another page? should i write javascript function or using PHP for better solution. For example , when checkbox is checked pass checkbox value , if not checked pass 0

This is my table:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" onclick="allChecked(this.checked);"/></th>
    <th>Invoice No.</th>
    <th>Invoice Date</th>
    <th>Due Date</th>
    <th>Invoice Amount</th>
    <th>Open Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<form id="frmPaySelected">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="invoice_no[]" value="IN000001" onclick="addTotal(this.checked, 1500.00);"/></td>
    <td>IN000001</td>
    <td align="right">11 Jan, 2018</td>
    <td align="right">10 Feb, 2018</td>
    <td align="right">1,500.00</td>
    <td align="right">1,500.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="invoice_no[]" value="IN000003" onclick="addTotal(this.checked, 1500.00);"/></td>
    <td>IN000003</td>
    <td align="right">16 Jan, 2018</td>
    <td align="right">15 Feb, 2018</td>
    <td align="right">2,150.00</td>
    <td align="right">1,500.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="invoice_no[]" value="IN000004" onclick="addTotal(this.checked, 259.50);"/></td>
    <td>IN000004</td>
    <td align="right">30 Jan, 2018</td>
    <td align="right">31 Mar, 2018</td>
    <td align="right">900.00</td>
    <td align="right">259.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong>Total: </strong></td>
    <td><div style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold;">5,538.25</div></td>
    <td><div id="divTotalPayAmount" style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold;">0.00</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" align="right"><input type="button" value="Pay Selected" onclick="alert('Submit Selected!');"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</form>
</table>
```

"javascript checkbox function"

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    var totalOpenAmount = 0;
    var blnUpdateCheckAll = true;

    function allChecked(checkValue) {
        var chkInvoices = document.getElementsByName('invoice_no[]');

        blnUpdateCheckAll = false;

        for(i = 0; i < chkInvoices.length; i++) {
            if(chkInvoices[i].checked != checkValue)
                chkInvoices[i].click();
        }

        blnUpdateCheckAll = true;
    }

    function updateAllChecked() {
        var chkInvoices = document.getElementsByName('invoice_no[]');

        var c = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < chkInvoices.length; i++) {
            if(chkInvoices[i].checked)
                c++;
        }
        if(c < i)
            document.getElementById('chkAll').checked = false;
        else
            document.getElementById('chkAll').checked = true;
    }

    function addTotal(checkValue, openAmount) {
        if(checkValue)
            totalOpenAmount += openAmount;
        else
            totalOpenAmount -= openAmount;

        if(blnUpdateCheckAll) updateAllChecked();

        document.getElementById('divTotalPayAmount').innerHTML = totalOpenAmount.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Depends on how you want to do the processing - server side via php or client side via js.  If you want to do it server side, you'll need to add a method and and action to your `<form>` tag, use POST, and your checkboxes will be in `$_POST['invoice_no']` as an array

Comment: can i get a more clearly answer ? ivanivan

Comment: we dont know any more about your project than what you have posted. looks like you should just be posting to a php script; if so, add a form action with that scripts name, and a submit button.